# unable to define fill colour in line chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am workng on chart js(2.3.0) with angular 1.5. I am painting 4 canvas(line chart) by ng-repeat.i am unable to define fill colour in chart.i am able to plot the chart but if i define any colours it takes black colur as fill colour.

My canvas code

```
<canvas id="smallchart{{$index}}" class="chart chart-line" 
   chart-data="smallgraphdata[$index]" chart-labels="smalllabels[$index]"
   chart-options="smallchartoptions" chart-colors="smallchartcolours" 
   width="100%" height="100%">
</canvas>
```

When I define

`$scope.smallchartcolours =['f43dgf']`

it works but i need a opacity in my colour so i have to use rgba value;
so i defined like below:

```
$scope.smallchartcolours = [{
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(156,255,252, 0.42)'
}];
```

But every time i define this, my chart fill colour gets black. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$scope.smallchartcolours = ['rgba(156,255,252, 0.42)']` what happen when you use like this?

Comment: "Cannot parse rgb value"  it shows in console

Comment: it worked when i removed space before opacity value!